# VB6 - What does the following operation do: x = b(1) + b(2) * &H100&?

Tags: vb6

Reading through some old code for doing some data that is streamed from a database.  Not super familiar with VB6.

This is a rough idea of what the code looks like. Just not entirely sure what the value of x or y would be?  What does *&H100& do?  What does Chr$(b(3)) do?

```
Private Sub Sub1()
Dim b() as Byte

' b is then read from a file, a bytes string, or from a database object

x = 0
x = b(1) + b(2) * &H100&

y = ""
y = y & Chr$(b(3))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = b(1) + b(2) * &H100&
```

...converts two consecutive bytes into a 16-bit integer. The second byte is the high part of the integer. If the two bytes were (say) 10 and 20, the result would be (20 * 256) + 10, or 5130

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense. And how about the Chr$(b(3)) operation? Some conversion to character from the byte 3?

Comment: Jim thanks but I figured that out, too. Chr(56), for example, returns the character from the ASCII representation of the integer 56.

Answer (score 3):

Jim Mack gave an excellent answer already.

Some more supporting information from [Type Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters):

> Visual Basic supplies a set of identifier type characters that you can
> use in a declaration to specify the data type of a variable or
> constant.
>
> & Long    Dim M&

> You can also define an integer literal as a hexadecimal (base 16)
> number with the &H prefix

So `&H100&` is a hexadecimal number being converted to a long.  The `&` on the end is forcing conversion to a long to possibly prevent an overflow error.

From [Chr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function):

> Returns a String containing the character associated with the
> specified character code.

The Chr() function returns a variant type, while Chr$() returns a string.

Comment: Thanks as well! Appreciate the clear answer! Not entirely familiar with VB6 but getting there.

Comment: Careful! The *Type Characters* link is to the **VB.Net** documentation not **VB6**. As it happens the information you've copied into the answer also applies to VB6, but that won't always be true. Nice answer otherwise

Comment: Yeah...a lot of the pages specifically for VB6 are simply gone from MSDN.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - To clarify a couple of points: first, the trailing & in `&H100&` needed in some cases. It forces long-integer math, without which you can get overflow errors when the other multiplicand is a short integer > 256. Second, `Chr()` yields a `Variant` of type `String`, and `Chr$()` yields a `String` directly.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: what Jim said. You should edit your answer and correct the last sentence. The way you phrased it, it's wrong. VB generally has these string function couple, e.g. Mid() and Mid$(). All work the same way: the former returns a _VARIANT_ of type _String_, where the latter returns an actual String variable. In practice, the outcome is the same with the exception that the string variations are faster.